# Three condition button based on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, zurb-foundation

I am fairly new to Angular an I am feeling lost in all of it's documentation.

**Problem:**
I am trying to create a button which has three phases:

**Add User - Remove Request - Remove User**

- So if you want to add a user you click on the **Add button**, which
  sends an ajax request to the server and if successful the button
  should then turn into a **Pending button**.
- In the pending state if you click on it again, your request will be
  deleted and it will again turn back to a **Add button**.
- The third phase is also if the user has accepted your request, you
  will be seeing a **Remove user button** which when you click on
  you will again see the **Add button** which if you click you will get
  the **Pending button** and so forth.

*So basically it is a familiar button if you've been using social networks.*

When the page is loaded the user will see the users and the buttons for each user based on it's current condition (so the server will be handling this part). From this part Angular should handle the ajax calls and changing of the button per user connection request.

**What I need:**
I have done the Ajax part for sending the request. However I can't manage to handle the part which Angular needs to change the button to it's new state (for a specific user on the list, meaning the list has more than 1 user which you can send connection add/pending/delete requests.) I have tried different solutions but failed till now.

Some of my messy failure code which I have left unfinished:

**Angular Controller:**

```
foundationApp.controller('ConnectionButtonCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.addUser = function(id) {
            $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : '/api/connections/add/'+id,
            dataType: "html",
        })
        .success(function() {
            $scope.activeId;
            $scope.activeId = id;
            $scope.isAdd = function(id){
                return  $scope.activeId === id;
            };

        })
    };
    $scope.removeRequest = function(id) {
            $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : '/api/connections/removeRequest/'+id,
            dataType: "html",
        })
        .success(function() {
        })
    };

});
```

**Laravel Blade View:**

```
<span ng-controller="ConnectionButtonCtrl"  >
    <a class="label radius fi-plus" ng-show="!isRemove(1)" ng-click="addUser(1)"></a>
    <a class="label radius fi-clock info" ng-show="isRemove(1)" ng-click="removeRequest(1)"></a>
    <a class="label radius fi-x alert" ng-show="!isAdd(1)" ng-click="removeUser(1)"></a>
</span>
```

Comment: what is $connection->id ? (I'm not familiar with laravel)

Comment: @NexusDuck I forgot to mention that the "{{" and "}}" are for the PHP framework views (blade) and I have changed the syntax for Angular to "<%" and "%>" so there won't be conflicts

Comment: @NexusDuck let's say those are row numbers or simply the user id which we want to connect to, for example: ng-show="!isremove(1)"

Comment: Shouldn't remove request  be of  `DELETE` type instead of `GET`?

Comment: @softvar The server side is handling things well. I'm struggling to get the ID of the scope and tell the controller to only set the value of for example isAdd for a specific scope to true or false

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use $index or user.id.  I am assuming your buttons are on the same line as the user.  If that's true then you are probably using an ng-repeat.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <a class="label radius fi-plus" ng-show="!isRemove(user.id)" ng-click="addUser(user.id)"></a>
  <a class="label radius fi-clock info" ng-show="isRemove(user.id)" ng-click="removeRequest(user.id)"></a>
  <a class="label radius fi-x alert" ng-show="!isAdd(user.id)" ng-click="removeUser(user.id)"></a>
  <div> some user information {{user.name}} </div>      
</div>
```

Then you can pass the id of the user with your ajax request. You can also use $index (as a parameter in my code instead for the index of the user in the array).

Comment: I am ok with this part. What I need is the Controller to tell the ng-show for example scope.isRemove(user.id) = true. This is what I'm struggling with I can't manage to use the user.id in the scope section (of the controller.js file) to give it a true or false value.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand, but typically for a scenario like this I have a var e.g., $scope.added which is an array. $scope.added = [ ].  Then each element of the array represents the state of (in your case) each user row. So $scope.added[$index] = true would mean that the user at index n is true.  You can also use a hash if you prefer to relate to user.id.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/hhOdNTV6ogJHhtXcM03a?p=preview**

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.users = {
      user1: {
        'status': 'add',
        'statusClass': 'positive'
      },
      user2: {
        'status': 'pending',
        'statusClass': 'waiting'
      },
      user3: {
        'status': 'remove',
        'statusClass': 'negative'
      }
  };

  $scope.handle = function (user) {
    if (user.status === 'add') {
      alert('send request to the user');
      user.status = 'pending';
      user.statusClass = 'waiting'
    }
    else if (user.status === 'pending') {
      alert('send request to discard a connection req');
      user.status = 'add';
      user.statusClass = 'positive'
    }
    else {
      alert('send req for removal');
      user.status = 'add';
      user.statusClass = 'positive'
    }
  };
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="user in users">
    User {{$index+1}} - <button ng-click="handle(user)" ng-class="user.statusClass">{{ user.status }}</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hhOdNTV6ogJHhtXcM03a?p=preview

Comment: As you can see I am not using a ng-repeat and the loop is done on the server side by php. However your code has given me a lot of help. how is it possible to get index id in the controller to update the scope of a certain user without the ng-repeat?

Comment: How will you render the users without a loop?

Comment: Will you be sending a separate req for each user?